# Como coger la información del fútbol de ésta página?

Tags: python, scraping

estoy intentando coger la información de esta página
[https://www.marca.com/futbol/primera-division/clasificacion.html] para dichos resultados y aunque por el mismo método extraigo información de otras páginas similares, de ésta, se me resiste y no logro comprenderlo.

```
URL = 'https://www.marca.com/futbol/primera-division/clasificacion.html'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
'''# Equipos = soup.find_all('div',class_='styled__ContainerAccordion-e89col-11 HquGF') # ! LUEGO QUITAR CUANDO SE INCLUA EN LA CLASIFICACIÓN GENERAL
Equipos = soup.find_all ('span', class_='styled__TextRegularStyled-sc-1raci4c-0 glrfl')'''

Equipos = soup.find_all ('p', class_='ue-c-table-ranking__team-name')
print (URL)
print ('Equipos: ', Equipos)
for i in range (0,20):
    print (i, ' Equipo: ', Equipos[i])
```

después de correrlo, lo único que me devuelve es una lista vacía.

```
Equipos: []
```

y el error correspondiente del for, que hasta que no corrija el vacío, no funcionará como es lógico.

¿Podéis ayudarme? ¿Qué es lo que me falta? Gracias anticipadas

Comment: Sé lo de... artículo 45 del RGPD, pero es solo para mi, no va a salir de ninguna de las formas de mi ordenador y no voy a sacar mas rédito del que consiga acertar. Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Debes tener en cuenta que estás intentando acceder dentro de `#shadow_root`, así que tendrás que usar **Selenium**.

En la solución que se propone en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73334005/18475298) puedes ver qué debes hacer para llegar a la tabla que necesitas.

La diferencia es que en tu caso, debes acceder dentro de 2 `#shadow-root` anidados. En el edit de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48756722/18475298) se realiza este proceso.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon el contenido esencial de los enlaces _en la respuesta misma_. Piénsalo: si los enlaces llegan a caer, y un lector más adelante tiene un problema similar, ¿cómo sabrá qué contenía el enlace?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, ahora no voy a perder tanto tiempo investigandolo. Gracias, selenium para esto solo no me gusta y no me resulta práctico, casi que lo que voy a hacer es un copiar y con python formatear lo que hay en la memoria, como solo se hace una vez a la semana, creo, que es mas práctico y rápido.

Comment: @padaleiana Disculpa, soy nuevo. ¿Con compartir el permalink de las respuestas bastaría, o tengo que copiar la respuestas manualmente en la mía?

Comment: Una imagen y links no son válidos como respuesta. Te invito a leer [answer]. Haz clic en [edit] y copia el código como texto y da una breve explicación, a modo de resumen, con el contenido esencial de los enlaces que has compartido. No copies y pegues el contenido de otro post aquí, eso tampoco sería lo adecuado. Saludos

Comment: @Jose Veo Por lo que dices parece que quieres obtener los datos de los equipos semana tras semana. En esta página web vienen los datos de cada partido (tendrías que transformarlos previamente para obtener los datos correspondientes de cada equipo) listos para descargar en un CSV. Lo actualizan tras cada partido jugado, así que quizá pueda servirte de ayuda: https://www.football-data.co.uk/spainm.php

Comment: Gracias, otra información la obtengo de laliga.com en la que si funciona soup, pero quería ésta por las estadísticas detalladas que se muestran como yo quiero. Viendo la página que me sugieres, tiene un montón de datos, pero no los que yo quiero, aún así, muchas gracias.